# neovim launched to edit command line doesn't use default configuration

Tags: zsh, neovim, oh-my-zsh

I use zsh, oh-my-zsh, neovim, alacritty, and zsh-vi-mode oh-my-zsh plugin. My EDITOR is set to `/usr/local/bin/nvim -u /Users/aleksander/.config/nvim/init.lua` When I try to edit a command line via vv in normal mode neovim launches but not reading the usual config nor regular plugins. Whats the reason? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is `$ZVM_VI_EDITOR` set to? That's the variable the plugin uses to launch the editor.

Comment: It was set to `vim`! Documentation says `You can change the editor by ZVM_VI_EDITOR option, by default it is $EDITOR.` so I didn't suspect it

Comment: But I `source⋅$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` before setting $EDITOR 

Comment: The short version is that your comment helped